# How to have multiple spring boot batch Configuration class

Tags: java, spring-batch

If I want to have several jobs in my batch project. Each file only contains a single job.

**Job 1:**

```
@Configuration
public class StartTest1 {

    @Autowired
    JobBuilderFactory jobBuilderFactory;

    @Autowired
    StepBuilderFactory stepBuilderFactory;

    @Bean
    public Job processJob() {
        return jobBuilderFactory.get("processJob1").incrementer(new RunIdIncrementer())....;
    }
    ....
}
```

**Job 2:**

```
@Configuration
public class StartTest2 {

    @Autowired
    JobBuilderFactory jobBuilderFactory;

    @Autowired
    StepBuilderFactory stepBuilderFactory;

    @Bean
    public Job processJob() {
        return jobBuilderFactory.get("processJob2").incrementer(new RunIdIncrementer())....;
    }
    ....
}
```

I tried to set @Configuration annotation for each class. But only one job executes at run time. How can I do to have multiple job files?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think that the problem is that both job beans have the same name `processJob`, so one overwrites the other when the application context gets built. The simplest solution would be to use unique bean names like the names you are giving the `Job`s: `processJob1`, `processJob2`.

Comment: Thanks for the help! After having unique names. All jobs work now!

Comment: Good to know it works! Can you please accept my answer then?

Answer (score 0):

I find another way,

> set different bean name!

**Job 1:**

```
@Configuration
public class StartTest1 {

    @Autowired
    JobBuilderFactory jobBuilderFactory;

    @Autowired
    StepBuilderFactory stepBuilderFactory;

    @Bean("job1")
    public Job processJob() {
        return jobBuilderFactory.get("processJob1").incrementer(new RunIdIncrementer())....;
    }
    ....
}
```

**Job 2:**

```
@Configuration
public class StartTest2 {

    @Autowired
    JobBuilderFactory jobBuilderFactory;

    @Autowired
    StepBuilderFactory stepBuilderFactory;

    @Bean("job2")
    public Job processJob() {
        return jobBuilderFactory.get("processJob2").incrementer(new RunIdIncrementer())....;
    }
    ....
}
```